# Optimization Problem with Constraints

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem

\begin{align}
 \min_{X_{1},X_{2},y_{11},y_{12},y_{21},y_{22}}  \;   \; p_{1}X_{1}+p_{2}X_{2}& \\
 \text{s.t}\;   \; X_{1}^{\beta} &= y_{11} + y_{12} \hspace{2.5pt}\notag \\
 X_{2}^{\beta} &= y_{21} + y_{22} \notag \\
 Y_{1} &= \frac{y_{11}}{c_{11}} + \frac{y_{21}}{c_{21}} \notag \\
    Y_{2} &= \frac{y_{12}}{c_{12}} + \frac{y_{22}}{c_{22}} \notag \\
    X_{1},&X_{2},y_{11},y_{12},y_{21},y_{22} > 0 \notag \\
\end{align}

with parameters $\beta \in (0,1)$, $p_{1},p_{2}>0,$ $Y_{1},Y_{2}>0$ and $c_{11},c_{12},c_{21},c_{22}>1$.

I am having lots of trouble finding the solution to this minimization problem, which in principle, looks easy. The first order conditions are

\begin{align}
&(1)\hspace{10pt}X_{1} : p_{1} - \lambda_{1}\beta X_{1}^{\beta-1} = 0 \\
&(2)\hspace{10pt}X_{2} : p_{2} - \lambda_{2}\beta X_{2}^{\beta-1} = 0 \\
&(3)\hspace{10pt}y_{11} :  \lambda_{1} - \frac{\mu_{1}}{c_{11}} = 0 \\
&(4)\hspace{10pt}y_{12} :  \lambda_{1} - \frac{\mu_{2}}{c_{12}} = 0 \\
&(5)\hspace{10pt}y_{21} :  \lambda_{2} - \frac{\mu_{1}}{c_{21}} = 0 \\
&(6)\hspace{10pt}y_{22} :  \lambda_{2} - \frac{\mu_{2}}{c_{22}} = 0 \\
\end{align}

where $\lambda,\mu$ are the Lagrange multipliers. Am I missing a constraint or something? Is there a way to go forward?

One natural option seems to use equations (3) and (5), and (4) and (6) to find the following conditions

\begin{align*}
(7)\hspace{10pt}\frac{p_{1}c_{11}}{X_{1}^{\beta-1}} = \frac{p_{2}c_{21}}{X_{2}^{\beta-1}}
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
(8)\hspace{10pt}\frac{p_{1}c_{12}}{X_{1}^{\beta-1}} = \frac{p_{2}c_{22}}{X_{2}^{\beta-1}}
\end{align*}

However, how can (7) and (8) hold simultaneously?

Comment: Any information about $p_1$, $p_2$ like positive?

Comment: Yes, they are positive. Just edited including this info

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Say all the $c's$ are the same. In that case, the minimum is easy to compute. Now, when they are different is where I have trouble.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong - assumed $Y_1$, $Y_2$ are also optimization variables.

Comment: Ah, no! These two are parameters!

Comment: I would use the constraints for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to get rid of two variables, say, $y_{21}$ and $y_{22}$. Then the constraint for $X_2$ becomes of the form $X_2^{\beta}=A-ay_{11}-by_{12}$ ($A$, $a$, $b$ new positive constants). Then get rid of $X_1$ and $X_2$ in the objective, to have a convex problem with only two variables $y_{11}$ and $y_{12}$. The constraint is a triangle. It is likely to have no critical point (unless $a=b$ which is a very special case), so the solution is on the boundary. However, the boundary is not feasible, which makes it unlikely to have a solution in most cases.

Comment: A minor correction: the constraint for the two variables is a *rectangle*, not a triangle.

Comment: When you say it is in the boundary, does it mean that there are infinite answers on the “line” of the rectangle or that the y’s are 0? 

Cleary I wrote “positivity” constraints instead of “non-negativity” constraints, which might have been the case!

Comment: I mean one $y$ is zero (infeasible), that is no minimum in this case, only suboptimal solutions when the corresponding $y$ tends to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The method of Lagrange multiplier may fail in some cases.

Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22}} ~ p_1X_1 + p_2X_2 \qquad\qquad (P)\\
 &\mathrm{subject ~ to}\quad X_1^\beta = y_{11} + y_{12},\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\ X_2^\beta = y_{21} + y_{22}, \\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 Y_1 = y_{11}/c_{11} + y_{21}/c_{21},\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 Y_2 = y_{12}/c_{12} + y_{22}/c_{22},\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22} \ge 0.
\end{align*}
In some cases, at minimum, some of $X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22}$ are zero (see the example later), so the method of Lagrange multiplier fails.
We need the KKT conditions instead.
By the way, if your constraints are $X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22} > 0$, in such cases, no minimum occurs, which is similar to:
$f(x) = x^2$ has no minimum on $(0, 1]$.

**An example**:

For $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, \beta = 1/2, Y_1 = 3, Y_2 = 4, c_{11} = 3, c_{12} = 6,
c_{21} = 7, c_{22} = 4$,
the optimization problem is given by
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22}} ~ 2X_1 + 3X_2 \qquad\qquad (P1)\\
 &\mathrm{subject ~ to}\quad \sqrt{X_1} = y_{11} + y_{12},\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\ \sqrt{X_2} = y_{21} + y_{22}, \\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 Y_1 = y_{11}/3 + y_{21}/7,\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 Y_2 = y_{12}/6 + y_{22}/4,\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22} \ge 0.
\end{align*}
The minimum occurs at
$(X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22}) = (4356/25, 4356/25, 9, 21/5, 0, 66/5)$.

The KKT conditions are given by
\begin{align*}
 2 - \lambda_1\frac{1}{2\sqrt{X_1}} - s_1 &= 0, \\
 3 - \lambda_2\frac{1}{2\sqrt{X_2}} - s_2 &= 0, \\
 \lambda_1 - \frac13 \mu_1 - s_3 &= 0, \\
 \lambda_1 - \frac16\mu_2 - s_4 &= 0, \\
 \lambda_2 - \frac17\mu_1 - s_5 &= 0, \\
 \lambda_2 - \frac14\mu_2 - s_6 &= 0,\\
 s_1 X_1 &= 0, \\
 s_2 X_2 &= 0, \\
 s_3 y_{11} &= 0, \\
 s_4 y_{12} &= 0, \\
 s_5 y_{21} &= 0, \\
 s_6 y_{22} &= 0, \\
 s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5, s_6 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}
You may solve this system to obtain the solution.

---

By the way, the problem (P) is equivalent to the following convex problem:
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22}} ~ p_1X_1 + p_2X_2 \qquad\qquad (P2)\\
 &\mathrm{subject ~ to}\quad X_1^\beta \ge y_{11} + y_{12},\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\ X_2^\beta \ge y_{21} + y_{22}, \\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 Y_1 = y_{11}/c_{11} + y_{21}/c_{21},\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 Y_2 = y_{12}/c_{12} + y_{22}/c_{22},\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\
 X_1, X_2, y_{11}, y_{12}, y_{21}, y_{22} \ge 0.
\end{align*}
*Note*: We replace the constraints $X_1^\beta = y_{11} + y_{12}, X_2^\beta = y_{21} + y_{22}$ with
$X_1^\beta \ge y_{11} + y_{12}, X_2^\beta \ge y_{21} + y_{22}$.

We used Matlab+CVX to solve the convex problem (P2).